# Accessing an OWIN server on a different system from the client

Tags: signalr, owin

I've worked through the OWIN self-hosting tutorials and have a web app and a console client interfacing with the OWIN self-host inside of Visual Studio 2012. When I run the host on a separate machine and point my clients to that IP, the dynamically generated hub file does not show up and the `$.connenction.myHub` is undefined.

All of the examples use localhost, and so far, I'm just running this inside of VS 2012. Is it possible to have the OWIN host on one system and the clients on another? I've added the CORS to the startup class.

Comment: Yup, it's possible.  Add some code to your question so we can look through that.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be an issue with networking between two virtualbox VMs. I installed the web app on a test server on a different system and was able to get the OWIN host talking it. Haven't crossed domains yet, but that may not be an issue with this project.